# Binary file saved to Evernote from Chrome Extension via Thrift is garbled after Unicode conversion

Tags: javascript, utf-8, google-chrome-extension, thrift, evernote

EDIT: this problem boils down to UTF-8 conversion, please discuss here:  [UTF-8: should it hold that string = encode(decode(string))? And if not, how to achieve it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13786628/1887947)

I am trying to save a PDF file to Evernote from a Chrome extension using the unofficial [Kanda software's API](https://github.com/kandasoftware/evernote-sdk-javascript). Essentially, it uses Thrift and provides methods for creating and sending a data structure as per Evernote API.
For testing, I use a sample PDF file with byte length of 2898.

When the CreateNote() method is called, the data ultimately gets into the SDK's thrift.js where it is being UTF-encoded and placed into appropriate data structure. These functions are called:

```
    writeString:function(str) {
        var result = Array.prototype.map.call(this.encode(str).split(""), this.stringToHex); // <----- I tried to skip this encoding for the data body
        this.writeI32(result.length);
        for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
            this.ra.push(result[i]);
        }
    },
...
    encode:function(string) {
        string = string.replace(/\r\n/g, "\n");
        var utftext = "";
        for (var n = 0; n < string.length; n++) {

            var c = string.charCodeAt(n);

            if (c < 128) {
                utftext += String.fromCharCode(c);
            }
            else if ((c > 127) && (c < 2048)) {
                utftext += String.fromCharCode((c >> 6) | 192);
                utftext += String.fromCharCode((c & 63) | 128);
            }
            else {
                utftext += String.fromCharCode((c >> 12) | 224);
                utftext += String.fromCharCode(((c >> 6) & 63) | 128);
                utftext += String.fromCharCode((c & 63) | 128);
            }
        }
        return utftext;
    },
...
    writeI32:function(i32) {
        var i32out = new Array();
        i32out[0] = 0xff & i32 >> 24;
        i32out[1] = 0xff & i32 >> 16;
        i32out[2] = 0xff & i32 >> 8;
        i32out[3] = 0xff & i32;

        var result = Array.prototype.map.call(i32out, this.byteToHex);
        for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            this.ra.push(result[i]);
        }

    },
```

I don't really understand how Thrift works at this level and why it needs to encode ALL the data including the binary attachment body, but as you see it results in the data for PDF (and all other string data to be transported, for that matter) being UTF-encoded, so the .length is now 3018 bytes. It all goes through the API and the file is shown on Evernote front-end (see pic), but it is not decoded back, being 3018 bytes in size, so the PDF is botched.

[Image of the result on Evernote front-end](http://www.evernote.com/shard/s138/sh/8324aaf4-6192-4796-8975-e415110dad04/a48067cc91f8ffc8b1a40b08192ae7e8)

I tried to brute-force a solution by skiping the encode() call for the data body only, but this results in the file being somehow discarded at all.

**Would you please give me any clue whether the problem lies in my misunderstanding, the SDK, or the Evernote back-end, and how can it be fixed? I have lost my sleep over this.**

---

For reference: I get the original file via XMLHttpRequest, like this:

```
function getLink(url, callback) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('GET', document.getElementById('url1').value, true);
  xhr.responseType = 'text';
  xhr.overrideMimeType('text/plain; charset=x-user-defined');

  xhr.onload = function(e) {
    if (this.status == 200) {
      // Note: .response instead of .responseText
      alert("String(this.response) " + String(this.response).length);
      alert("String(this.responseText) " + String(this.responseText).length);
      blob = String(this.response);
      AddNote1(url, blob, function(response) {
        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML += String(response).replace(/\n/g, "<br/>") + "<br/>";
        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML += blob.slice(1, 20);
        } );
      }
    };
  xhr.send();
  }
```

The resulting data looks okay and the string.length is 2898.
I then proceed to add the note as described in examples. Again, it all checks out well and the byte string goes into CreateNote() intact, so this is again just for reference:

```
function AddNote1(Name, ContentFile, callback)
{
    var noteStore = get_NoteStore();
    var note = new Note();
    note.title = Name;
    var na = new NoteAttributes();
    //na.author = "someone";
    na.sourceURL = Name;
    na.source = "web.clip";
    note.attributes = na;

    var data = new Data();
    var resource = new Resource();
    binaryData = ContentFile;
    data.size = binaryData.length;
    alert(binaryData.length + '*' + ContentFile.length);
    data.bodyHash = raw_md5(binaryData);
    data.body = binaryData;
    resource.mime = "application/pdf";
    resource.data = data;
    var resAttributes = new ResourceAttributes();
    resAttributes.fileName = String(Name).replace(/^.*[\/\\]/g, '');
    resource.attributes = resAttributes;
    note.resources = Array(resource);
    //important to set correct content
    var content = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>"
        + "<!DOCTYPE en-note SYSTEM \"http://xml.evernote.com/pub/enml2.dtd\"><en-note>";
    content += String("Oi Wei").replace(/\n/g, "<br/>") + "<br/>";
    content += "<en-media type=\"application/pdf\" hash=\"" + md5(binaryData) + "\"/>";
    content += "</en-note>";
    note.content = content;
    //response is a created note
    //callback function process response
    var response = noteStore.createNote(Eventnote.Auth.get_auth_token(), note);
    if (callback !== undefined) {
      callback(response);
      }
```

Comment: I figure out that this should be fixed by decoding the file before it is being processed. This still leaves the characters with higher Unicode numbers garbled. Is there any Javascript utf8_decode() implementation that doesn't have this problem?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any Javascript utf8_decode() implementation that doesn't have
>   this problem?

Taken from [here](http://ecmanaut.blogspot.com.au/2006/07/encoding-decoding-utf8-in-javascript.html):

```
function encode_utf8( s )
{
  return unescape( encodeURIComponent( s ) );
}

function decode_utf8( s )
{
  return decodeURIComponent( escape( s ) );
}
```